# Blackberry: Command line build and application auto-start

Tags: blackberry, mobile

I have an application which is built from command line (ANT) using J2ME Polish. As such, this application is defined through a build.xml, not from Blackberry JDE project files.

What I need to do is have this application auto-start. This is easy enough to do once the application has been run for the first time ([example](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Using-FLAG-AUTO-RESTART/td-p/331517/highlight/true)). However, this does require the application to be manually run by the user (which I want to avoid).

The JDE provides options which you can check to enable auto-start, and from ANT:

```
  <cldc runonstartup=="true"...
```

Will do the trick. The question is, how do I integrate this into a Polish buiild (i.e. into a Polish build.xml which is also building for other platforms)?

Anyone know what the auto-start option in the JDE actually does / what it changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the way to do this is, unfortunately, to change the J2ME-Polish source! As outlined in this [bug report](http://developer.berlios.de/bugs/?func=detailbug&bug_id=16901&group_id=1246) the J2ME Polish build framework (at version 2.1.4) doesn't pass on the RIM-MIDlet-Flags-x JAD attribute to RAPC.

The changes are relatively simple - merely passing on the RIM-MIDlet-Flags-1 value if defined in the JAD, otherwise setting it to zero (as the original 2.1.4 source does).

The diff (from 2.1.4) source:

```
Index: /enough-polish-build/source/extensions/de/enough/polish/blackberry/JarToCodFinalizer.java
===================================================================
--- /enough-polish-build/source/extensions/de/enough/polish/blackberry/JarToCodFinalizer.java   (revision 315)
+++ /enough-polish-build/source/extensions/de/enough/polish/blackberry/JarToCodFinalizer.java   (revision 316)
@@ -36,6 +36,7 @@
 import java.util.Calendar;
 import java.util.Locale;
 import java.util.Map;
+import java.util.List;
 import java.util.Properties;

 import org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException;
@@ -185,6 +186,13 @@
            }
        }
        File iconFile = null;
+       Map jadProperties;
+       try { 
+           jadProperties = FileUtil.readPropertiesFile( jadFile, ':' );    
+       } catch (Exception e) {
+           e.printStackTrace();
+           throw new BuildException("Unable to read JAD file " + e.toString() );
+       }
        if (mainClassName != null) {
            try {
                /*
@@ -230,12 +238,26 @@
                        "MicroEdition-Configuration: CLDC-1.1",
                        //"MIDlet-1: Demo," + iconUrl + ",",
                        "MIDlet-1: " + env.getVariable("MIDlet-Name") + "," + iconUrl + ",",
-                       //"MIDlet-Icon: " + iconUrl,
-                       "RIM-MIDlet-Flags-1: 0"
+                       //"MIDlet-Icon: " + iconUrl
                };

+               /* Ensure that if RIM-MIDlet-Flags is defined in the JAD, it is
+                * passed on to RAPC to create the COD file.
+                * See https://developer.berlios.de/bugs/?func=detailbug&group_id=1246&bug_id=16901
+                * for details.
+                */
+               ArrayList newEntriesList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(newEntries));
+               final String flagsKey = "RIM-MIDlet-Flags-1";
+               String flagString = (String)jadProperties.get(flagsKey);
+               if (flagString == null) {
+                   flagString = "0";
+               }
+               flagString = flagString.trim();
+               System.out.println("JarToCodFinalizer setting " + flagsKey + ": " + flagString);
+               newEntriesList.add(flagsKey+ ": "  + flagString);
+
                File rapcFile = new File( jadFile.getParent(), codName + ".rapc");
-               FileUtil.writeTextFile( rapcFile, newEntries );
+               FileUtil.writeTextFile( rapcFile, newEntriesList );
            } catch ( IOException e ) {
                // this shouldn't happen
                e.printStackTrace();
@@ -367,7 +389,6 @@
            // now rewrite JAD file so that it is ready for OTA download:
            // (first backup JAD file:)
            //FileUtil.copy(jadFile,  new File(jadFile.getParent(), jadFile.getName() + ".bak") );
-           Map jadProperties = FileUtil.readPropertiesFile( jadFile, ':' );    
            Object[] keys = jadProperties.keySet().toArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
                String key = (String) keys[i];
```

Comment: Committed with some changes see polish thread http://www.j2mepolish.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=3379#3379

Answer (score 0):

Another polish user :)

Take a look at  [BB](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/RIM-Flags-how-to-make-meaningful/m-p/45785;jsessionid=FD7A88BE1929274F4A3BD3B8FB47A38C) forums the 2nd post. Then using what we know about polish and [jad attributes](http://www.j2mepolish.org/cms/leftsection/documentation/building/build.xml/build-section.html#jad)

Add this to your jad section of your build.xml

```
<jad>
 <attribute  name="RIM-MIDlet-Flags" 
   value="1" 
  if="polish.vendor == BlackBerry" />
</jad>
```

I haven't tested this but the logic seems to be valid :) Let me know if it works or not.

Comment: That won't (and doesn't) work - already tried it. 
Polish Blackberry applications are not MIDlets, despite appearances. The Polish build process translates the MIDlet into a Blackberry UIApplication (see http://www.j2mepolish.org/cms/leftsection/documentation/platforms/blackberry.html#blackberry-gui). 
Setting RIM-MIDlet-Flags only works for MIDlets, so alas the method you describe doesn't work.

Comment: I spoke too soon - apparently RIM-MIDlet-Flags *does* work not non-MIDlets... I must be doing something wrong. I will give it a shot again and try and debug whats wrong.

Comment: Great :) let me know if this works. hehe

Sorry forgot to mention you might need to change the number in this case "1" to something else depending on the device/OS I just noticed some versions list 32 as a valid number for autostart.

Comment: Definitely doesn't work. JarToCodFinalizer (part of the 'Polish Blackberry build chain) hard-codes RIM-MIDlet-Flags to '0', which is passed to RAPC. 
Without the flags being passed to RAPC, the app doesn't get the-autostart attribute.
I think I have a fix, however (which requires changing and building J2MEPolish!).

Comment: Let me know the patch and I will make sure it get comitted :) Been meaning to add losts of stuff to their BB support.